# Как сделать Содержание и переход к главам в readme.md на Github?

Tags: github

Как сделать принцип работы "содержания" как в MS Word?
Например, есть содержание и при нажатии на какой-либо пункт, автоматом перепрыгивает на него в тексте.

Comment: якоря. Это ещё с бородатых времён поддерживается

Comment: @Kromster опечатка, исправил

Comment: @ArchDemon а можно ссылку хотябы...а то не нахожу информацию.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если необходимо, чтоб вся информация была только в одном README.md и соответственно была навигация для удобности пользователя, лучше конечно воспользоваться якорями, про которые упомянул в комментариях @ArchDemon

Помести в нужном месте якорь:

```
<a name="твоё_название"></a>
```

и там где это необходимо, ссылку на этот якорь:

```
[Текст ссылки](#твоё_название)
```

Comment: Данный ответ, решает поставленную задачу

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно делать внутренние ссылки к заголовкам, то не обязательно использовать html-теги, как рекомендует @user262779.
Можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
[отображаемое название](#название-заголовка)
```

То есть в круглых скобках все буквы в нижнем регистре и слова разделены дефисом. Более того, если в названии есть скобки, знаки пунктуации и т.д. их писать не следует. Еще момент: неважно какого уровня заголовок, в круглых скобках всегда один символ решетки!
Так же рекомендую ознакомиться с, как я понимаю, [переводом руководства на русский](https://gist.github.com/Jekins/2bf2d0638163f1294637).

---

Я, например, редактирую файл в intellij idea и на этапе когда у меня написано:

```
[отображаемое название]()
```

Достаточно добавить в круглые скобки "#", чтобы появился выпадающий список со всеми возможными вариантами. Очень удобно.